# Using Ajax to update a table on a page in django

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to the table in my all-reviews whenever someone checks one of the filters at the top using ajax. However, when a filter is checked it is getting the entire page back including things like the navbar and then updating the table with the entire page data instead of just the filtered reviews. The issue I believe is with my view since its rendering the all-reviews.html page but I cannot figure out how to do it properly where the returned data doesn't include the navbar and other unneeded information that is imported into my base.html. Lastly, I am trying to make it so that if they click a filter, it loads the new data, but then if they uncheck the filter, or check a different one the data is refreshed again. Currently after the first time a filter is checked nothing happens if subsequent filters are checked or unchecked.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "app.css" %}" />
    {% block css_files %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body id="page">
    {% include "./includes/navigation.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-n/4gHW3atM3QqRcbCn6ewmpxcLAHGaDjpEBu4xZd47N0W2oQ+6q7oc3PXstrJYXcbNU1OHdQ1T7pAP+gi5Yu8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    {% block js_files %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**all-reviews.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    All Reviews
{% endblock %}

{% block css_files %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "trading_log/all-reviews.css"%}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="filters">
        <form id="filters_form" class="" action="" method="GET">
            <input type="checkbox" id="macd_filter" name="filters" value="macd_filter" onchange="triggerFilterFormSubmit()">
            <label for="macd_filter">MACD</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="rsi_filter" name="filters" value="rsi_filter" onchange="triggerFilterFormSubmit()">
            <label for="rsi_filter">RSI</label>
        </form>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="review_data">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th class="" scope="col">Review #</th>
                <th class="" scope="col">Associated Trade</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for review in reviews %}
                {% include "trading_log/includes/review.html" %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block js_files %}
    <script src="{% static "trading_log/filters.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**review.html**

```
{% if review %}
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion{{review.id}}" class="clickable">
    <th scope="">{{ review.id }}</th>
    <td class="">{{ review.trade_id.id }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center accordian-container" colspan="8" style="padding-bottom: 0px;padding-top: 0px;">
        <div id="accordion{{review.id}}" class="collapse">
            {% include "trading_log/includes/review-card.html" %}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

**filters.js**

```
function triggerFilterFormSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $('#filters_form').attr('action'),
        data: $('#filters_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#page").html(data)
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
};
```

**views.py**

```
class AllReviewsView(ListView):
    model = Review
        
    def get(self, request):
        user_id = request.user.id
        filters = request.GET.getlist("filters")
        filtered_reviews = []
        reviews = Review.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
        if filters: 
            for filter in filters:
                for review in reviews:
                    if review.nine_min_potential_macd_div:
                        filtered_reviews.append(review)
        else:
            filtered_reviews = self.get_queryset().filter(user_id=user_id)
        context = {
            "reviews": filtered_reviews
        }
        return render(request, "trading_log/all-reviews.html", context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use .load() in jquery.  There is a better way using django's built in [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) method along with jquery ajax.  Unlike .load() it's incredibly fast.

Consider the following very simple example to inject or refresh part of your page with django/ajax/jquery.  Building on this simple example you can create some complex and robust ajax interactions.

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def inject_some_content(request):
    data = dict()
    context = {'my_context': 'some_context'}
    data['my_content'] = render_to_string('app_name/injected_content.html',
        context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import inject_some_content

urlpatterns = [
    path('inject-some-html/', inject_some_content, name='inject_some_content'),
[
```

**your_page.html**

```
<div id="target-div"> <!-- your content gets put here by ajax --> </div>

<button type="button" class="load-content" href="{% url 'inject_some_content' %}">Click Me</button>

<script>
    var loadThisContent = function () {
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("href"),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#target-div').html(data.my_content);
            }
        }
        )
    };
    $('.load-content').on('click', loadThisContent);
</script>
```

**injected_content.html**

```
<h1>Hello World!!  I just got put here by Ajax!  Here is {{my_context}}!</h1>
```

Lastly, as long as you are using the ajax method in Jquery, avoid including the *minified* version of the jquery library, which for some unexplained reason drops the ajax method.

Comment: Hi, just saw this. Unfortunately I am working today. It will be a few more hours before I can try implementing it. Ty for the response, I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Best of luck!  Feel free to follow up with your experience.

Comment: seems to of worked tyvm!

Comment: Woops thought I did that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `load()`. Manage your code with if statements.

(logic is `if (filter_2.clicked){ $('#colTwo').load(your_page_url + ' #colTwo');}`)

Filter.js:

```
function triggerFilterFormSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $('#filters_form').attr('action'),
        data: $('#filters_form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#page").html(data)
            $('#filter_result').load(your_page_url + '#filter_result');
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Im sorry, I am still learning how alot of this stuff works. Where would I put that logic?